# Python Matplotlib Circle questions

Tags: python, matplotlib, file-io

I have a few questions about Matplotlib.

How I could get a circle's fill color to be of RGB value (0-255)? I can't seem to find any way to get the circle to take an int between 0-255 for an RGB value, only a float between 0-1.

How do I get matplot to take parameters from an optional file input, otherwise default to defaults in the program?

Can I get rid of the axis limits completely when plotting shapes, so that my shapes don't get clipped by either axis?

```
import numpy as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

//set default value for rgb values for a circle
R = random.nextint(0,255)
G = random.nextint(0,255)
B = random.nextint(0,255)


//check to see if there is a file that will override the default value 
for rgb value - this is one thing that I need help with



circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.3, color=(0.7,0.9,0.1))
circle2 = plt.Circle((0.2, 0.3), 0.3, color=(0.3,0.2,0.4))
//this is what I would like to happen
circle3 = plt.Circle((0.2, 0.3), 0.3, color=(R,G,B)) - another thing that I need help with

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.add_artist(circle2)

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("output.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a valid matplotlib RGB color array from a tuple of RGB values in the range between 0 and 255 you may simply divide by 255.

```
color = np.array((R,G,B)) / 255.
```

To get a figure without axes that clip the artist you may pin the axes to the edge of the figure

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
ax.axis("off")
```

To read in a file you may use `open`

```
with open("filename", "rb") as f
    content = f.readlines()
```

depending on the format of the file you may use numpy instead to directly get the numbers into an array,

```
arr = np.loadtxt("filename")
```